# Trying to get the results from first query to search a second query

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been working on a social network, i have a fanpages table that a user can create a profile for their favorite band or celebrity and another table called friends where they can subscribe to the fanpages. i then want the requests to appear in notifications for the fanpage admin to except.
after the first sql query it returns fanpages with multiple values but if i echo the next $sql query it shows that its only selecting one result to query instead of all of them.

so basically i need to query fanpages table for all fanpages created_by the user logged on ($log_username), then i need to take those fanpages and query the friends table to find out if anyone has requested to subscribe to the users fan pages??

this line of code $fanpage_requests = "$fansubSql"; outputs SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user2='fan4' AND accepted='0' ORDER BY datemade ASC as the only result but there should be 2 results as both fan3 and fan4 have requests.

thanks for your help Michael

```
$fanpage_requests = '';

$fansql = "SELECT created_by, fanpage_name FROM `fanpages`  WHERE created_by = '$log_username' ";
$fanquery = mysqli_query($db_conx, $fansql);
$fannumrows = mysqli_num_rows($fanquery);

if($fannumrows < 1){
    $fanpage_requests = 'No friend requests';
} else {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fanquery, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $fanpage_name = $row["fanpage_name"];
        $created_by = $row["created_by"];

        $fansubSql = "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user2='$fanpage_name' AND accepted='0' ORDER BY datemade ASC";
        $fansubQuery = mysqli_query($db_conx, $fansubSql);
        $fansubNumrows = mysqli_fetch_row($fansubQuery);
        $fanpage_requests = "$fansubSql";

        if($fansubNumrows < 1){
            $fanpage_requests = "blah blah"; 
        }

        while ($fansubRow = mysqli_fetch_array($fansubQuery, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $fansubreqID = $fansubRow["id"];
            $fansubuser1 = $fansubRow["user1"];
            $fansubdatemade = $fansubRow["datemade"];
            $fansubdatemade = strftime("%B %d", strtotime($datemade));

            $fansubthumbquery = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT avatar FROM users WHERE username='$user1' LIMIT 1");
            $fansubthumbrow = mysqli_fetch_row($thumbquery);
            $fansubuser1avatar = $thumbrow[0];
            $fansubuser1pic = '<img src="user/'.$user1.'/'.$user1avatar.'" alt="'.$user1.'" class="user_pic">';

            if($fansubuser1avatar == NULL){
                $fansubuser1pic = '<img src="images/avatardefault.jpg" alt="'.$user1.'" class="user_pic">';
            }

            $fanpage_requests .= '<div id="friendreq_'.$fansubreqID.'" class="friendrequests">';
            $fanpage_requests .= '<a href="user.php?u='.$fansubuser1.'">'.$fansubuser1pic.'</a>';
            $fanpage_requests .= '<div class="user_info" id="user_info_'.$fansubreqID.'">'.$fansubdatemade.' <a href="user.php?u='.$fansubuser1.'">'.$fansubuser1.'</a> requests friendship<br /><br />';
            $fanpage_requests .= '<button onclick="fanReqHandler(\'accept\',\''.$fansubreqID.'\',\''.$fansubuser1.'\',\'user_info_'.$fansubreqID.'\')">accept</button> or ';
            $fanpage_requests .= '<button onclick="fanReqHandler(\'reject\',\''.$fansubreqID.'\',\''.$fansubuser1.'\',\'user_info_'.$fansubreqID.'\')">reject</button>';
            $fanpage_requests .= '</div>';
            $fanpage_requests .= '</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation. [mysqli_fetch_row](http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_row) does NOT return a number. It returns ONE record from the query. Look at the examples in the documentation: you need to use `mysqli_fetch_row` inside a loop to retrieve all records.

To know the number of rows returned by a query, use [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/mysqli_num_rows).

Comment: ok i looked into what you sugested and changed the first part to look like this $fanpage_requests = '';

    $fansql = "SELECT created_by, fanpage_name FROM `fanpages`  WHERE created_by = '$log_username' ";
    
 if ($fanquery = mysqli_query($db_conx, $fansql)){
  
  while($fanrow = mysqli_fetch_array($fanquery, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $fanpage_name = $fanrow["fanpage_name"];
            $created_by = $fanrow["created_by"];
   
            $fansubSql = "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user2='$fanpage_name' AND accepted='0' ORDER BY datemade ASC";

Comment: but still doesn't make a difference

Comment: Debug your code: use "echo" to print the values of variables or queries before they are executed. Use "print_r" to display the records returned by your queries. Enable error reporting, check your error logs. Tell us what exactly you need help with, post a short and relevant code snippet, and the exact error message you are getting. You don't use "mysqli_error()", how do you know if one of your queries is failing?

Comment: ok if i echo $fansql i get :SELECT created_by, fanpage_name FROM `fanpages` WHERE created_by = 'Jeff'  (jeff being the user logged in) so its solving $log_username correctly.

Comment: echo $fannumrows echos the number 6 which is correct there are 6 fanpages created by jeff

Comment: print_r $row outputs this:Array ( [created_by] => Jeff [fanpage_name] => Russell Howard ) Array ( [created_by] => Jeff [fanpage_name] => Audi cars ) Array ( [created_by] => Jeff [fanpage_name] => Star Wars ) Array ( [created_by] => Jeff [fanpage_name] => The Matrix ) Array ( [created_by] => Jeff [fanpage_name] => Green Day ) Array ( [created_by] => Jeff [fanpage_name] => Guns N Roses )

Comment: print_r $fansubSql outputs: SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user2='Russell Howard' AND accepted='0' ORDER BY datemade ASCSELECT * FROM friends WHERE user2='Audi cars' AND accepted='0' ORDER BY datemade ASCSELECT * FROM friends WHERE user2='Star Wars' AND accepted='0' ORDER BY datemade ASCSELECT * FROM friends WHERE user2='The Matrix' AND accepted='0' ORDER BY datemade ASCSELECT * FROM friends WHERE user2='Green Day' AND accepted='0' ORDER BY datemade ASCSELECT * FROM friends WHERE user2='Guns N Roses' AND accepted='0' ORDER BY datemade ASC

Comment: its at this point it fails it reaches the if($fansubNumrows < 1){
            $fanpage_requests = "blah blah"; 
        } and it outputs blah blah so its checking the records but suggesting that there are no requests waiting, but if you look in phpmyadmin 3 records have accepted = 0 created by jeff

Comment: if i do print_r ($fansubNumrows) it out puts this: Array ( [0] => 31 [1] => Ben [2] => Star Wars [3] => 2013-03-13 14:10:49 [4] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 33 [1] => Jeff [2] => The Matrix [3] => 2013-03-13 14:24:55 [4] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 32 [1] => Ben [2] => Green Day [3] => 2013-03-13 14:11:03 [4] => 0 )  which is correct 3 records created by jeff with 0 in accepted [4]

Comment: Click "edit" below your question to update it with more information. Code posted in comments is barely readable.